# What is the English Equivalent of Telugu proverb: ఊళ్ళో పెళ్ళి కి కుక్కల హడావిడి

Tags: proverb-requests

It means "For somebody's marriage street dogs are busy"

It means your sister/brother/children marriages, outsiders in marriage are too busy or behave like their own marriage which is unnecessary for them.

Examples:

1. Where someone is paying a lot of attention to something that has nothing to do with them.
2. Suppose you won something, but your friend doing more **RANTING** than you do. Actually which in unnecessary for him to do it.

Note: while posting an English Proverb, no need to include dog, it is just saying in our language. But please make proverb which is equivalent to examples. Just forget about dog here.

Comment: wow, look at her. You’d think it was *her* wedding.  Wow, you’d think *he* was the one who won.....

Comment: The descriptive second sentence isn't clear. These outsiders are too busy to do what and why does anyone care? Whose marriage is unnecessary for whom? And your examples seem contradictory with whatever sense can be made of the description. The outsiders seem to be _more_ interested. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a saying or a proverb for you, but I have a word:

upstage (Google)

> up·stage ˌəpˈstāj/ adverb & adjective adverb: upstage; adjective:
>   upstage
>
> verb verb: upstage; 3rd person present: upstages; past tense:
>   upstaged; past participle: upstaged; gerund or present participle:
>   upstaging
>
> > ```
> > 1.
> > divert attention from (someone) toward oneself; outshine.
> > "they were totally upstaged by their costar in the film"
> > synonyms:   outshine, outclass, eclipse, overshadow, trump, put someone in the shade, put to shame
> > "she is now upstaging the very person who brought her into the company"
> >     (of an actor) move toward the back of a stage to make (another actor) face away from the audience.
> > ```

Answer (score 1):

An idiomatic expression which comes close is ***stealing somebody else's thunder.***

TFD(idioms):

> **[steal somebody's thunder](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/thunder)**
>   to do something that takes attention away from what someone else has done
>
> I kept quiet about my pregnancy because Cathy was getting married, and
>   I didn't want to steal her thunder.
>
> Cambridge Idioms Dictionary, 2nd ed. Copyright © Cambridge University Press 2006. Reproduced with permission.